# Python coverage running the tests in local against the same service in docker

Tags: python, docker, code-coverage

I have a service code in python. For the functional tests, I run the tests in local against the same service built in a docker container because I want to test a REST API call or a Rabbitmq message, etc.

**Step 1.**

```
$ docker-compose.yml

  third_party_service_1:
  ...

  third_party_service_2:
  ...


  my_service:
    build:
      context: .
  ...
```

**Step 2.**

```
$ docker-compose up --build -d
```

**Step 3.**

```
$ coverage run -m pytest tests/functional
```

Obviously, the coverage does not work because the code in the docker image is the code copied from the local.

Is there a way to collect the coverage in this situation?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** 
I mean, I don't get the coverage from the functional tests because the code that is running because of the tests, is not the local code where I run the coverage and pytest commands. The functional tests know that they have to attack the docker image that I built. So, for the coverage, it is like you're launching the tests against a third party service, because it is not able to know which code is executed.

```
---------------------
|    LOCAL          |
| my_service code   |
|                   |
| I run:            |
| $ coverage run... |
---------------------

---------------------
|    DOCKER         |
| my_service code   |
|  (up&running)     |
---------------------
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean with "the coverage does not work because the code in the docker image is the code copied from the local"?

Comment: @kalehmann I edited my question. I hope I explained myself now. Thanks.

Comment: I think I got your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your tests and coverage-report inside the docker container with [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/):

```
docker-compose run my_service coverage run -m pytest tests/functional
```

This will run your coverage report inside the docker container for the `my_service`